# Tech lead interviewing and manager still allowing her to run wild

Tags: manager, team

Im working on a software development team. We are a small team and our tech lead has told us she is interviewing to move to another team.

The tech lead usually works alone and pretty much much built everything by herself and nobody else really understands how it works.

I expected my manager to put her into consultant/knowledge transfer mode but he's still allowing her to go off and build things unilaterally. I'm concerned that the team is not ready to support our products without this person and my manager doesn't seem to recognise this.

Should I tell him my concerns? I'm also considering interviewing to leave the team because I don't think it's fair to expect me to support these products without any handover or documentation.

Edit: I report to my manager, not the tech lead

Comment: Do you report directly to your manager or to your team lead?

Comment: @Erik I report to my manager, not the tech lead

Comment: _"I report to my manager, not the tech lead"_  So there is your answer - express your concerns regarding knowledge transfer and her unilateral work to your manager. Then the ball is in his court and you can't be blamed if stuff hits the fan at a later stage.. - even if you might work in another team in the future..

Comment: perhaps she has told you but not the manager yet. Maybe check in with her first?

Answer (score 7):

I would certainly bring this up as a potential issue. Keeping in mind that your lead doesn't currently have a transfer offer and (from what I understand) is transferring to another team in the same company, it might simply be that your manager has agreed with the lead that once she's completed the interviews, there will be a knowledge transfer period before the move happens.

It's also possible that your manager thinks no transfer is needed for whatever reason (whether it's "she still works here" or "you should have no problems taking over her job"), and in that case you and he disagree and it's probably good to make him aware of this.

The only way you can find out about your manager's current plan and he can learn about your concerns if you have a talk with him, so I'd just do that. But I'd suggest starting off with just asking those question openly.

Answer (score 0):

> Should I tell him my concerns? I'm also considering interviewing to
> leave the team because I don't think it's fair to expect me to support
> these products without any handover or documentation.

No.

If you are planning to leave the team anyway, then keep your opinion to yourself. Try to find a team that you think will be more "fair".